# Amazon DynamoDB InvalidSignatureException

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

From this code I'm getting the error below

```
require "vendor/autoload.php";
use Aws\Common\Aws;
use Aws\DynamoDb\DynamoDbClient;
use Aws\DynamoDb\Enum\ComparisonOperator;
use Aws\DynamoDb\Enum\KeyType;
use Aws\DynamoDb\Enum\Type;

$aws = Aws::factory(array(
'key'    => '[clipped]',
'secret' => '[clipped]',
'region' => Region::US_WEST_1
));

$client = $aws->get("dynamodb");
$tableName = "ExampleTable";

$result = $client->createTable(array(
    "TableName" => $tableName,
    "AttributeDefinitions" => array(
        array(
           "AttributeName" => "Id",
           "AttributeType" => Type::NUMBER
        )
     ),
     "KeySchema" => array(
        array(
           "AttributeName" => "Id",
           "KeyType" => KeyType::HASH
        )
    ),
    "ProvisionedThroughput" => array(
        "ReadCapacityUnits"    => 5,
        "WriteCapacityUnits" => 6
    )
));

print_r($result->getPath('TableDescription'));
```

I'm getting the following error when trying to add a table into AWS's DynamoDB.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Aws\\DynamoDb\\Exception\\DynamoDbException: AWS Error Code:
InvalidSignatureException, 
Status Code: 400, 
AWS Request ID: [clipped], 
AWS Error Type: client, 
AWS Error Message: Signature expired: 20130818T021159Z is now earlier than  
20130818T021432Z (20130818T022932Z - 15 min.), 
User-Agent: aws-sdk-php2/2.4.3 Guzzle/3.7.2 curl/7.21.6 PHP/5.3.6-13ubuntu3.9\n  thrown in
/var/www/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Aws/Common/Exception/NamespaceExceptionFactory.php on
line 91
```

So far I've:

- Checked to see if Authentication Key and Secret Key were correct, they were.
- Updated cURL
- When I put false authentication permissions in, the error didn't change.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

It seems that your local system time might be incorrect. I've had a similar problem with AWS S3, where my system clock was skewed by 30 mins.

If you're running ubuntu, try updating your system time:

```
sudo ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com
```

Comment: on mac `sudo ntpdate -u time.apple.com`

Comment: I literally wasted my whole day around this! Thanks for this answer, fixed my issue instantly.

Comment: This can of course be run on most other flavors of Linux, not just Ubuntu.

Comment: you nailed it buddy!! Thank you !!

Comment: I have this message on Windows 7. How to solve this?

Comment: @Guus Fix your system time to either be updated automatically or just update it manually to be the same as time.gov

Comment: I cannot believe this was my problem all along. It's the little things, am I right? fml

Answer (score 2):

You can also restart your date service to solve the problem if you've already got ntpdate installed.

```
sudo service ntpdate stop
sudo service ntpdate start
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `docker-machine` on Mac, you can resolve with this command:

`docker-machine ssh default 'sudo ntpclient -s -h pool.ntp.org'`

Answer (score 1):

Quick note for vagrant projects: this is usually resolved by `vagrant reload`.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly OP question, but this is top google response for "InvalidSignatureException DynamoDB", which has many underlying causes.

For me, it was because my body contained emoji, 100% reproducible. Worked around by encoding the body (in my case stringified json) using `encodeURIComponent`.